# How to test if a Magento store is in "Demo Mode"

Tags: php, magento

Through the configuration you can set a Magento store into "Demo Mode". In this mode a banner appears on top of the webshop mentioning that orders will not be fulfilled.

Is there an easy way to test if the store is currently in demo mode or not?

As an extra insurance against accidental visitors I want to disable the checkout process of the webstore in the template if the demo mode has been enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check for demo mode with:

```
$bTest = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('design/head/demonotice');
if ($bTest)
    // Is demo mode
```

or

```
$sTest = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/demonotice');
if ($sTest == '1')
    // Is demo mode
```

To switch demo mode on/off in the backend use `System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Display demo store notice -> yes/no`.

Comment: Thanks -- this looks very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do your test in the front end with prototype, add an id to the code to the demo stroe notice and then use if($(’your-demo-id’))

As for turning off the cart, you can turn that off easy enough in admin or put a redirect match into your apache htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Just Select Yes/No click Save Config to save the change.

```
Admin==>System==>Configuration==>
Design==>HTML Head==>Display Demo Store Notice
```

[image]